# Get TR which contains value

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table with rows like:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="http://blabla/">
            <b>This is where I filter</b>
        </a> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

I will get are `tr` with text between `<b>` contains some word

After a lot of try, I went step by step

```
var $trFind = $('tbody tr').map(function () {
    if ($('b', $(this)).html().contains(val))
        return $(this);
});
```

but `$trFind` is an array of object, and I can't hide, show them. I would like to paginate this `tr` something like:

```
$trFind .slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
```

I hope I was clear about my issue. I tried to put all related code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) and [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). Something like `$('tbody tr').has('b:contains("filter")')`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure I understand your question, but an easier way to get the tr-elements that contain a certain text is by using :contains()

```
$("tr td b:contains('This is the text/droids your looking for')");
```

[Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

You can use that selector to show/hide all of those elements by:

```
//Show them
$("tr td b:contains('Show all TR with this text')").show();

//Hide them
$("tr td b:contains('Show all TR with this text')").hide();
```

Comment: tr has few td that I'm not interested, I want just the text within <b>. Thanks for your help

Comment: Also you should use `$("tr b:contains()");`

Comment: Updated answer after feedback =)
@RokoC.Buljan ;)

Comment: @JacobRastad I've seen that, +1